# What does the cache control value control in a static resource?

Tags: static-resources

While creating a static resource there is an option for specifying **Cache Control**, This contains two values **Public** and **Private**.
[image]

What does these values actually control?.

Initially had an Idea that if its **public**, it can be refered from outside salesforce.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the docs:

> Private specifies that the static resource data cached on the
>   Salesforce server shouldn’t be shared with other users. The static
>   resource is only stored in cache for the current user’s session.
>
> Note Cache settings on static resources are set to private when
>   accessed via a Force.com site whose guest user's profile has
>   restrictions based on IP range or login hours. Sites with guest user
>   profile restrictions cache static resources only within the browser.
>   Also, if a previously unrestricted site becomes restricted, it can
>   take up to 45 days for the static resources to expire from the
>   Salesforce cache and any intermediate caches.
>
> Public specifies that the static resource data cached on the
>   Salesforce server be shared with other users in your organization for
>   faster load times.

There's a good article on static resources and Visualforce on the developerforce wiki at:

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Delivering_Static_Resources_with_Visualforce

Answer (score 15):

To distill the docs down:

- using either, you'll never suffer from a stale cache so long as you use the URLFOR() function, which busts the cache with a timestamp whenever you update the static resource

**Public** resources:

- will be accessible from a public-facing Force.com Site

**Private** resources:

- require you to be authenticated with a Session Id (eg, in the org, in a portal, logged into a Site)

The rest of the details are behind the scenes :-)

Comment: thanks! and in my use case, using a Static Resource with `cache control = private` on an SSO-controlled Sites page results in a 401 (not found).  Took me the longest time to realize this as same static resource cache control = private loaded just fine on a non-sites Page.